# OPENGL, C++, SDL2 - Не рисуется

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl2

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

const float width=1024;
const float height=800;

const float pos_x=SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;
const float pos_y=SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED;

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Event event;

int main(){
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("Window", pos_x, pos_y,
            width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    /*SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, 
                        SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);*/

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    while(window!=NULL){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type==SDL_QUIT)
                window=NULL;
        }

        //glClearColor(255, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor3f(200, 0, 0);
            glVertex2f(10, 10);
            glVertex2f(20, 10);
        glEnd();

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
}
```

Хочу линию нарисовать, но не рисуется, поч?

Comment: Координаты вершин возьмите поменьше. `0,0` и `1,0`, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я скопировал Ваш код и поменял следующее

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
```

а также выставил более толстую линию и поправил координаты

```
glLineWidth(10); // сделаем линии очень толстыми, что бы увидеть
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(200, 0, 0);
glVertex2f(0, 0); // рисуем с центра
glVertex2f(1, 1); // в верхний правый угол
glEnd();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

И увидел линию с центра. Если рисовать линию с 10,10 в 10,20, то это за пределами экрана и ничего не будет видно.

Comment: Наконец-то, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

вполне возможно что надо сменить на версию 3.0. у меня например поддерживалась sdl2 только 3.0 версию. и еще, хотя sdl2 всё равно, какую вы установите версию. прикол в том что в 3 версии glBegin и glEnd устарели. они были только во второй версии. в 3 версии надо рисовать с помощью шейдеров. хотя я еще рисовал без шейдеров с помощью функций, которые забыл как называются уже, потому что в последнее время только с помощью шейдеров писал. я думаю что sdl2 может быть нарисует ваши линии. короче поменяйте на 3.0.

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);

Comment: а лучше сразу ставить 2.2 версию и координаты переуточнить.  я рекомендую использовать 0,0 - 1,1

Comment: Я бы поставил плохую оцунку, но не хочу. Кароче говоря по твоему методу нифига не работает!